# Why does PPID change?

Tags: linux, pid, child-process

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Fork failed.");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("CHILD:\nPID: %d, PPID: %d, UID: %d\n", pid, getppid(), getuid());
    } else {
        wait(&status); //wait for child to terminate
        printf("PARENT:\nPID: %d, PPID: %d, UID: %d\n", pid, getppid(), getuid());
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
CHILD:
PID: 0, PPID: 4309, UID: 1000
PARENT:
PID: 4310, PPID: 3188, UID: 1000
```

Why is 4309 the PPID of the child? Shouldn't it be 4310?
Thnak you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't print out the parent's PID in the parent code, so you have nothing to compare it to. `fork()` returns the *child's* PID to the parent. In your example it appears that the parent has PID 4309 and the child 4310.